# Comparison of colors lightness

Tags: colors, comparison

I need to compare color lightness by their hex values.

I am sure that RGB `FFFFFF` (white) is lighter then `000000` (black). I am also sure that `FFFF00` is lighter than `FF0000`.

But what about other values in between? Which would be the "lightest" in each of these cases?

- `FF00FF` and `00FFFF`
- `112233`, `221133`, `332211`

Is there a pattern to determine which color is lighter?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space specifically the parts on HSV and HSL should be good starting points for your question.

Comment: @Lukap: Did my solution provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Split it in RGB components and decide for each comopent what the lightness factor is.
I.e. if you think red is generally 'lighter'  than blue then that factor is different.
I think these factors can be quite subjective.

If you don't want to use these factors, just add all values of the RGB components.

Maybe the following story helps (or not):
http://scienceblogs.com/mixingmemory/2006/12/does_red_weigh_more_than_blue_1.php